# Algorithm to approximate this cos(x) equation by successions

Tags: algorithms

I'm a little embarrassed, but I've get blocked solving this:

[image]

I have to "make an algorithm to aproximate the equation" above. That's all the details I know.

Comment: Is your problem understanding the mathematical formula, or implementing it in code?

Comment: @anorton I get stuck while trying understanding the math formula. I have no problems on implementation. Sorry for my English

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about the formula?  Do you know what $6!$ means?  If I told you "evaluate the formula with $n=3$ and $x=1$," could you do it?

Comment: I don't know how to "aproximate the value" of that formula. I mean, the instructions on a photo I got says: "Make an algorithm to aproximate the following [this part is cut] cosine(x). and then the above formula, like this :http://i.imgur.com/YE6AKeg.jpg

Comment: Ok.  Perhaps a better way they could have phrased the instructions is "When $n$ is large $\cos(x)$ is approximately $1-\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \cdots + (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$.  Use this to approximate $\cos(x)$."  So, you should pick some large value of $n$ (like $100$ or $1000$) and evaluate the expression on the right hand side of the equation.  Does that help make it clearer?

Comment: Yes, I'll try, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to evaluate the sum $a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_n$,
where 
the terms satisfy 
$$
a_0=1,
\qquad
a_{k+1}=(-1)^k \dfrac{x^2}{2k(2k-1)} a_k
$$